# Checking if name is on member list

Tags: java, jcreator

OK so the list is working but the problem is the checker. Here is the situation: there is a list of Member names, first the user will input a name. second, the program will check if the name is on the list. If the name is on the list it will display "OK", If the name is not on the list it will display "MEMBER DOES NOT EXIST". My problem is that the checker searches for the name but if the first member is already not equal to the name inputted by the user, "Member does not exist" will be displayed and the program just stops searching.

**for example:**

Memberlist

1. mike
2. albert
3. fred

**Input: mike**

**Output:OK**

but if

**Input: albert**

**Output: Member does not exist**

here is my code so far.

```
    class Node
    {
        protected String info;
        protected Node next;
        public Node(String value)
        {
            info = value;
            next = null;
        }
     }

     class LinkedList
     {
         private Node head;
         private Node head1;
         private Node head2;
         private int count;
         public LinkedList()
         {
         head = null;
         count = 0;
         }
         public void checker(String name)
         {

           for(Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next)
           {
              if(cur.info.equals(name))
              {

                 System.out.print("OK ");
                 return;
              }
              else
              {
                 System.out.print("member does not exist");
              }
           }
          }
```

It is not the whole code but my problem is mainly the checker

Comment: Where are you updating the value if head in your loop?

Comment: From the Insert method which i did not include would you like to see it?

Comment: Yes, please show where you are instantiating your `head` node.

Comment: BTW, `member does not exist` will be printed for every node that does not equal, until it is found.

Comment: oh ok here it is                                                                          

             public void insert( String name)
             {
           Node a = new Node(name);
           a.next = null;
           count++;
           if (head == null)
           {
          head = a;
          return;
              }
             for(Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next)
               {
             if (cur.next == null)
             {
             cur.next = a;
             return;
                 }
               }
               }

Answer (score 0):

in the first iteration of the for loop, you check whether the value equals to name. otherwise "Member not exists"

You must finish the loop and then only you can print member does not exists.

```
       for(Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next)
       {
          if(cur.info.equals(name))
          {

             System.out.print("OK ");
             return;
          }
       }

       System.out.print("member does not exist");
```

is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something as basic as:

```
int nameExist;
  for(Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next)
  {
     if(cur.info.equals(name))
     {
         nameExist++;
     }
  }
  if(nameExist>0){
      System.out.print("ok");
  }
  else{
      System.out.print("member does not exist");
  }
```